# unable to change legend color for amcharts when using custom legends

Tags: javascript, graph, visualization, amcharts

I have an amchart like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1ooed595/2/).In my legend i have the following code

```js
"legend": {
    "horizontalGap": 10,
    "useGraphSettings": true,
    "markerSize": 10,
     "data": [{
       "title": "Total_Balance",
       "value": getValue('balance'),
       "backgroundColor":"#0D52D1",
       "color": "#0D52D1"
     }, {
       "title": "Total_Paid",
       "value":getValue('paid'),
       "backgroundColor":"#04D215",
       "color": "#04D215"
     }]
  }
```

But the legend color still appears black.I'm unable to change the legend background color.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `useGraphSettings` as the property doesn't make sense when combined with your custom markers in the `data` array. `useGraphSettings` only applies when you're using legend markers generated directly from the graph objects, so combining the two leads to weird results.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1ooed595/3/)

Also note that `backgroundColor` is not a property of the data object and `value` isn't documented. It may work for now, but use at your own risk as undocumented properties can change or be removed without warning. Only `title`, `color` and `markerType` are supported.

Comment: if i implement this , now default legend item click functionality is not working. Do ihave to implement my own now ?

Comment: Yes, you have to implement your own [clickMarker](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#clickMarker) listener for the behavior you want for the `data` markers. `data` markers have no association with graph objects, so they're effectively user generated labels unless you tie in your own behavior with them. Here's an example, assuming "Total_Balance" refers to the first graph object and "Total_Paid" is the second graph object: http://jsfiddle.net/1ooed595/4

Comment: instead of doing this way,is there any way by default where i can show legend text and value (where value is sum of all the individual values in that category) exp:Total_Balance legend will have value which is sum of all the total balances in all years..

Comment: If "by default" you mean using the regular markers, then you can use the [`valueFunction`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#valueFunction) callback in the legend to display whatever value you want for each marker (note that the marker label is tied to the graph's [`title`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#title) property). The callback provides the graph object when you don't have a chartCursor enabled and you can use that object to access the chart's dataProvider and do your calculations there. Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/1ooed595/5/

Comment: this is exactly what i  was looking for. tq

Comment: @xorspark I am trying to implement similar feature using amcharts4, and refering the http://jsfiddle.net/1ooed595/4 but seems like legend settings are different in amchart4, can you please help me with this?

Comment: You can see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56548446/toggle-column-series-on-click-of-custom-legends-in-amcharts4-in-angular for code reference, what I have tried till now